# Me retorna undefined utilizando navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, programación-funcional, navigation

Porque me devuelve *undefined* al utilzar este código:

```
let tes = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  return {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lang: position.coords.longitude,
  };
});

console.log(tes);
```

Pero si dentro de la función en vez de poner `return` pongo `console.log` si devuelve el valor pero en consola, o sea de esta forma:

```
let tes = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  console.log({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lang: position.coords.longitude,
  });
});
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: prueba usando una función típica de ES5, capaz estas perdiendo el alcance

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que la función de geolocalización es asincrónica, esto quiere decir que cuando llamas console log e invocas la función, esta misma no ha devuelto algun valor (por eso sale undefined, porque no ha devuelto nada). Mira este ejemplo:

```
let tes = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  console.log("Acabo de terminar de obtener las coordenadas! Voy a devolver un valor.");
  return {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lang: position.coords.longitude,
  };
});

console.log("Uno");
console.log("Dos");
console.log("Tres");
console.log(tes);
console.log("Ya imprimi el valor de tes! Aunque no este listo!");
```

Da como resultado en la consola:

```
Uno
Dos
Tres
undefined <= Como tes no ha devuelto valor, estas haciendo console.log(undefined)
Ya imprimi el valor de tes! Aunque no este listo! <=Queda confirmado por este mensaje
Acabo de terminar de obtener las coordenadas! Voy a devolver un valor <= Hasta ahora la funcion tes devolvio un valor.
```

Debes de manejar estas funciones asincrónicas con promesas (te recomiendo usar async y await). Esto también explica porque al meter el console.log() en el callback este se ejecuta de manera correcta.